# SSL Certificate - Reason why the page is not trusted

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am not very familiar with the SSL Certificates and how they work.

However I succeed to install a SSL Certificate via cPanel of my shared hosting.

Please checkout this page: https://www.sportsdirect.bg/customer/account/create/

As you can see there is a problem with the certificate.

The padlock in the browser URL address is not green. Can you please tell me what can be the reason for this and how I can fix it ?

Comment: This is not a programming related question.  For more information, you should try searching.  A useful search might be "green address bar" or "Extended Validation Certificate".

Comment: Well it is green for me but generally clicking on the padlock icon will tell you why the browser thinks it's invalid.

Comment: Can you try it with Chrome ? It is green for Opera.. but not for the rest.

Comment: **Click on the padlock icon** and read what the browser says about it.

Comment: Certificate is not from a trusted authority

Comment: So i have to buy another one ?

Comment: Can you provide the details of how the certificate is installed, especially whether you have installed the full certificate chain, including the intermediary `RapidSSL SHA256 CA - G3` certificate with fingerprint `0e34141846e7423d37f20dc0ab06c9bbd843dc24`?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this by adding the missing certificate into the chain?

Answer (score 1):

Off topic for this site.

Your web server is not properly configured to deliver the full certificate chain, see https://serverfault.com/questions/633247/ssl-error-on-mobile-devices .

Check your [SSL Labs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=sportsdirect.bg&latest) and you will see **Chain Issues: Incomplete**.  Your intermediate certificate:

```
RapidSSL SHA256 CA - G3 
Fingerprint: 0e34141846e7423d37f20dc0ab06c9bbd843dc24 
RSA 2048 bits (e 65537) / SHA256withRSA
```

... is not in your server's trust store and is not being served.  Take a look at [How to install an Intermediate CA cert in Apache](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/43575).